# modelnames are not displaying in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below i have two auto complete textviews for displaying brand and model.when i am clicking brand texview it was showing what are the brands availabe in the server.

Response from json

```
{
  "RESULT": "SUCCESS",
  "BRANDS": [
    {
      "BRANDID": "14",
      "BRANDNAME": "471",
      "MODELS": []
    },
    {
      "BRANDID": "8",
      "BRANDNAME": "SC720WP",
      "MODELS": [
        {
          "MODELNAME": "150",
          "MODELID": "2"
        },
        {
          "MODELNAME": "C150WS",
          "MODELID": "3"
        }
]
}
```

But when I am clicking the models nothing was happing .

**model class**

```
public class BrandModelResult implements Serializable{



   public String RESULT=null;
    public List<Brands> BRANDS=null;

    public List<Brands> getBRANDS() {
        return BRANDS;
    }

    public void setBRANDS(List<Brands> BRANDS) {
        this.BRANDS = BRANDS;
    }

    public String getRESULT() {
        return RESULT;
    }

    public void setRESULT(String RESULT) {
        this.RESULT = RESULT;
    }

    public static class Brands{
        public String BRANDID=null;
        public String BRANDNAME=null;
        public List<Models> MODELS=null;

        public String getBRANDID() {
            return BRANDID;
        }

        public void setBRANDID(String BRANDID) {
            this.BRANDID = BRANDID;
        }

        public String getBRANDNAME() {
            return BRANDNAME;
        }

        public void setBRANDNAME(String BRANDNAME) {
            this.BRANDNAME = BRANDNAME;
        }

        public List<Models> getMODELS() {
            return MODELS;
        }

        public void setMODELS(List<Models> MODELS) {
            this.MODELS = MODELS;
        }
    }
    public static class Models{
        public String MODELNAME=null;
        public String MODELID=null;

        public String getMODELNAME() {
            return MODELNAME;
        }

        public void setMODELNAME(String MODELNAME) {
            this.MODELNAME = MODELNAME;
        }

        public String getMODELID() {
            return MODELID;
        }

        public void setMODELID(String MODELID) {
            this.MODELID = MODELID;
        }
    }
}
```

**java**

```
private void getBrandModel()
    {


        String url = URLBuilder.getBrandUrl();
        String json = JSONBuilder.getJSONOwnViewStock("", "");
        SendToServerTask1 task = new SendToServerTask1(getActivity());
        task.execute(url, json);


    }
    private void SetBrandModel(String json)


    {

        try
        {


            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            BrandModelResult result_object = objectMapper.readValue(json, BrandModelResult.class);

            String brandmodel_result = result_object.getRESULT();

            Log.d("lead_result","" + brandmodel_result);
            brands=result_object.getBRANDS();


            Log.i("brands", "" + brands);
            int length=result_object.getBRANDS().size();


            if (brandmodel_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    brandList.add(brands.get(i).getBRANDNAME());


                }
                for (int i = 0; i < models.size(); i++) {

                   // BrandModelResult.Models model = models.get(i);
                    //models=model.getMODELNAME();

                    modelList.add(models.get(i).getMODELNAME());


                }

            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load data please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapterSearch = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, brandList);
        brand.setAdapter(adapterSearch);
        brand.setThreshold(0);
        ArrayAdapter adapterSearch1 = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, modelList);
        model.setAdapter(adapterSearch1);
        model.setThreshold(0);
    }
    private void SetOwnview(String json)
    {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try
        {
            OwnviewStockResult result_object = objectMapper.readValue(json, OwnviewStockResult.class);

            String ownview_result = result_object.getRESULT();
            Log.d("lead_result","" + ownview_result);


            if (ownview_result.equals("SUCCESS"))
            {

                ownview_stock = result_object.getSTOCKS();
                ownview_stock1.setText(ownview_stock);
                ownview_lead = result_object.getUSERS();
                ownview_lead1.setText(ownview_lead);



            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load data please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }





    public class SendToServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        private Context mContext = null;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        public SendToServerTask(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String url = params[0];
            String json = params[1];
            String result = UrlRequester.post(mContext, url, json);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            SetOwnview(result);
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
    public class SendToServerTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        private Context mContext = null;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        public SendToServerTask1(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String url = params[0];
            String json = params[1];
            String result = UrlRequester.post(mContext, url, json);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            SetBrandModel(result);
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```